# Does uninstalling psa-firewall (plesk firewall module) disable firewall?

Tags: firewall, iptables, mediatemple

I have a dv server with media temple and the plesk firewall module is causing a tonne of grief, it use to work, not anymore... unable to edit firewall rules through the module etc.

Does uninstalling this module, what i assume is known as the psa-firewall service prevent the firewall to work? its running centos 5 and the firewall looks to be iptables.

Answer (score 1):

that is just the package for plesk to interface with iptables with.. removing that and your firewall will still run.. to turn off your firewall

```
service iptables stop
```

if you don't want it to run on reboot

```
chkconfig iptables off
```

Comment: Iptables isn't a service, it can't be stopped, it's built into the kernel, you can just configure it to pass all traffic

Comment: you are sort of correct.. but in redhat/centos it has a init.d script when stopped flushes the rules and unloads the module. Also it can be done via chkconfig so iptables rules are never loaded

Answer (score 0):

check the [clean link](http://forum.parallels.com/showpost.php?p=407014&postcount=4) by IgorG from parallels :)